# the problem Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [localhost] appear in one computer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find the same problem always appear when numbers of computers share the one master, but I just in one computer publish and subscribe the message ,why I have the same problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229806/the-problem-couldn%27t-find-an-af_inet-address-for-%5Blocalhost%5D-appear-in-one-computer/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you have more than one NICs. For example, we usually have a Gigabyte Network Card and a Wi-Fi card in one laptop, if they all connect to the networks, ROS will be confused. You'd better add an extra line in you .bashrc file like:`export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2` to declare which local IP you want to use. Then your ROS knows which NIC should be used.

---

Originally posted by [lightbulb](https://answers.ros.org/users/26374/lightbulb/) with karma: 63 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0